# Why form not disapearing when input is valid ?(jquery validation plugin)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I'm showing errors on form, but even when form is valid (my form is with background and border) - it doesn't disappearing.

Here is screenshot:

[image]

Here is my js:

```
 $(".login").validate({
    rules: {

        "user[email]":{
            email: true,
            required: true
        },
         'user[password]': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            remote: {
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkpass",
            //url: "http://91.228.126.168:3000/checkpass",
            type: "get",
            data: {
              email: function() { return $("#user_email").val(); }
            }
          }
        }
    },
    messages: {
    "user[password]": {
    remote: "You entered wrong credentials"}
    },
     errorContainer: "#messageBox1",
     errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox1 ul",
     wrapper: "li"

})
```

CSS:

```
  #messageBox1{
display: none;
 }

   #messageBox1{
width: 280px;
padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
background: rgb(252, 248, 227) ;
border: solid 1px rgb(192, 152, 83);
margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You are using the forgotpass url to check the email field. Have you tried changing that.

Comment: @Mishra, that action checking if email exists. I deleted line with forgotpass.

Comment: Can you put your full code with HTML, JS and css on JSFiddle it would be easier for us to debug.

Comment: I will create jsfiddle and post link.

Comment: I can't reproduce it in jsfiddle.

Comment: Just copy paste all your HTML in JSFiddle and also link to all your JS Files and CSS files in the Manage Resources Option. It should work.

Comment: I mean I can't reproduce error, but I saw this problem in other questions, so I think it exists...

Comment: here is link to jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/33PGQ/29/

Comment: Do you have a link to your page where I can see the error ? I feel the css of your MessageBox is not getting properly set to display:none after the message is shown hence the box remains.

Comment: As I can see in your code above you are missing a double quote in the line: errorContainer: "#messageBox1, you should wrap #messageBox1 in a double quote. Probably that is the reason for the error.

Comment: it is just typo. i will fix it.

Comment: Form is disappearing only after click somewhere on the form. Can you tell me why ?

Comment: Your bug is not replicated on JSFiddle. Can you put a link to your working website where the bug is actually happening ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17827/discussion-between-shubhanshu-mishra-and-denmed)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what validation plugin you are using, but it seems to take control of your markup (correct me if I am wrong).

If you are open to using another validation plugin (which is markup structure independant), try [jQuery Validator](https://github.com/Livesys/jQuery-Validator)

See the demos & documentation for a how-to. The README contains the parameter info.

[Disclaimer: I developed this plugin for in-house use, but we just made it open source today]

Here's how I would handle your case with this plugin:

```
if($("#yourForm INPUT").Validate()){
   $("#messageBos1").hide();
} else {
   $("#messageBos1").show();
}
```

Of course, you should modify according to your needs, again, check the documentation and demos.